# Finding double mrp's in SQL

Tags: sql

I have table with `productcode` and `mrp` like

```
Pcode  MRP
1      30
2      30
2      35
3      100
4      150
4      150
5      45
6      120
6      122
6      125
```

I want to find which `productcodes` have more than two `mrp`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the count and use the having clause, you should get what you are looking for.

```
select pcode, count(pcode)
From tab
group by pcode
having count(pcode) > 1
```